# TypeError: undefined is not an object when using react native Drawer

Tags: navigation, drawer

```
ERROR  TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'InnerNativeModule.ins
tallCoreFunctions')
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable mod
ule (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the applicat
ion entry file path is incorrect.
      This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early in
itialization error when loading React Native.
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable mod
ule (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the applicat
ion entry file path is incorrect.
      This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early in
itialization error when loading React Native.
```

Comment: i used this doc:    https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator#installation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved by installing reanimated 2.3.0